# Avoid hardcoding when changing values in SQL Server trigger

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have a sql server "instead of insert" trigger that populates a single column (PromoCode). It all works perfectly, but I don't like the fact I have had to hardcode the columns in actual INSERT statement:

```
CREATE TRIGGER PopulateOrderPromoCode ON Order
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS BEGIN
    --// Get the Promo Code
    DECLARE @PromoCode int; 
    EXEC GetPromoCode @PromoCode OUTPUT;    

    --// Insert the order with the new Promo Code
    INSERT INTO Order (Id, CustomerId, PromoCode)
      SELECT Id, CustomerId, @PromoCode FROM inserted;
END
```

I would prefer to simply replace the value inside inserted.PromoCode with @PromoCode and then could use:

```
INSERT INTO Order 
  SELECT * FROM inserted;
```

Can this be done?

Comment: Are you dead certain that you will only ever insert one row at a time? If anyone (say, a DBA fixing a table late one night) ever inserts multiple rows in one statement, all the inserted rows will be assigned the same @PromoCode value.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use an INSTEAD OF INSERT trigger (in which you have to take over the insert logic)

Use a normal INSERT trigger (which allows you to do stuff **in addition to** the insert)

This assumes you can insert without a promo code (allows nulls) or the promo code defaults to something.

```
CREATE TRIGGER PopulateOrderPromoCode ON Order
FOR INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    --// Get the Promo Code
    DECLARE @PromoCode int;     
    EXEC GetPromoCode @PromoCode OUTPUT;        

    --// update the order with the new Promo Code
    UPDATE Order SET PromoCode = @PromoCode
      WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM inserted)
END
```

Answer (score 0):

INSERTED is a read only temporary table which can be accessed in any trigger. You can not modify it.

And the way you are using to perform an INSERT is the best way. So, there's nothing wrong with it. Its good to specify the columns while performing an INSERT (according to me).

Comment: True, but currently the trigger has to be updated when columns are added to the Order table! Ideally the trigger would be transparent as it only acts on the Order.PromoCode column, and shouldn't be interested in other Order columns.

Answer (score -2):

Dynamic SQL would be your only other option.  Try this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER PopulateOrderPromoCode 
ON  Order
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS 
BEGIN    
    --// Get the Promo Code    
    DECLARE @PromoCode int;         
    EXEC GetPromoCode @PromoCode OUTPUT;      

    DECLARE @InsertSQL nvarchar(2000), @SelectSQL nvarchar(2000)
    SET @InsertSQL = 'INSERT INTO Order ('
    SET @SelectSQL = 'SELECT '

    DECLARE @CurrentCol sysname
    SET @CurrentCol = ''



    WHILE EXISTS (  SELECT TOP 1 QUOTENAME(name)
                    FROM    sys.syscolumns 
                    WHERE   object_name(id) = 'Order'
                    AND     name <> 'PromoCode'
                    AND     name > @CurrentCol)
    BEGIN
        SET @CurrentCol = ( SELECT TOP 1 QUOTENAME(name)
                            FROM    sys.syscolumns 
                            WHERE   object_name(id) = 'Order'
                            AND     name <> 'PromoCode'
                            AND     QUOTENAME(name) > @CurrentCol
                            ORDER BY name)
        IF @CurrentCol IS NULL Break;

        SET @InsertSQL = @InsertSQL + @CurrentCol + ', '
        SET @SelectSQL = @SelectSQL + @CurrentCol + ', '
    END

    --Finish and concatenate the strings
    SET @InsertSQL = @InsertSQL + 'PromoCode) '
    SET @SelectSQL = @SelectSQL + '''' + @PromoCode + '''' + ' FROM INSERTED'

    DECLARE @MasterSQL nvarchar(2000)
    SET @MasterSQL = @InsertSQL + @SelectSQL

    EXEC (@MasterSQL)
END
```

BTW - "order" is a poor choice for a table name - it's also a reserved word in SQL.  Try Orders or OrderHeader.